# Using Twitter Bootstrap's .row element with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following snippet in my AngularJS app:

```
<div ng-repeat="proverb in proverbs">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will generate a `div` element with the class `col-sm-6` for every `proverb` in my `proverbs` array. My intention is to **display two columns** whenever a screen is big enough.

Despite not using Bootstrap's `.row` element, the above snippet works exactly as intended.

The question is, how could I include a `.row` element that would only appear every second iteration of `ng-repeat` so that I would get the following end result:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, given that whenever the sum of the spans of `.col` elements in Bootstrap is greater than 12 the next element gets pushed down, is there even any reason to use the `.row` class other than to guarantee a new row is generated before all columns are completely filled?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the .row then you could do [this](http://jsbin.com/quwumowavi/1/edit?html,output)

```
<div ng-repeat="proverb in proverbs">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <a href="#/{{langID}}/{{$index}}">{{proverb}}</a>
      <ng-show="$index % 2 == 0" br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't look right, see [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/fopotaroja/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You're right. AngularJS doesn't support steps over than 1 in ngRepeat out of the box.